# Option value not working but name appears fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 for(var i=0;  i<res.zone.length;  i++) {
      zone += '<option value="res.zone[i].zone_id">'+res.zone[i].zone_name+'</option>';
      $('#zone').html(zone);                                                                    
 }
```

`res.zone[i].zone_name` is fine. This gives the zone name. but `value` is not giving `zone_id` instead it gives value `res.zone[i].zone_id`. What I did wrong here?

Comment: You've put your variable inside a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
  zone += '<option value="' + res.zone[i].zone_id + '">'+res.zone[i].zone_name+'</option>';
```

You were passing `res.zone[i].zone_id` literally, so it didn't evaluate it.